# intelijIDEA cannot connect to Docker on another machine on LAN

Tags: docker, lan

I wanted to make it so that my second machine, which is on the local network with my computer, builds gradlew. Launched Docker on the second machine. I am trying to connect to it using intelijIDEA, but unfortunately IDEA writes that it cannot connect to the second machine on which Docker is located.

[image: error in IDEA]

But when i paste in browser 192.168.1.7, i see a docker's Get started web-page.

Whats wrong?

My notebook IP is 192.168.1.3
My hostMachine IP is 192.168.1.7
Connected with router. Firewall is off.
HostMachine - Windows10PRO
Notebook - Windows10Home

Comment: Please use the code tags to paste your error.

Comment: I guess problem is not Idea. Try `telnet 192.168.1.7 2375` to check connection. I can see only two reasons in this situation: 1. docker listening not 2375 port, 2. firewall still active. Also try to `ping 192.168.1.7`. If ping doesn't respond, firewall is probably active.

Comment: @rzlvmp ping ok ,i allow connection on port 2375TCP in firewall, But telnet cant connect.

Comment: @rzlvmp . I tried check port from internet. I opened 80 and 2375 ports in router. After this i checked this ports with service to check port. Port:80 is open from internet, but 2375 is closed. I think what docker dont work... but on remote machine i tryed telnet localhsot 2375 and connect was ok

Comment: @rzlvmp i think i find problem. 
  `TCP    127.0.0.1:2375  DESKTOP-FDUQBE0:0 LISTENING[com.docker.proxy.exe]`
And the second
`TCP    [::1]:2375  DESKTOP-FDUQBE0:0      LISTENING
 [com.docker.proxy.exe]`